# ReactJS: Conditional Rendering using Enums

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enums, jsx, conditional-rendering

I'm a bit new to React, and have been practicing by creating an application using the enums rendering method specified in [this article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/conditional-rendering-react/#enums).

However, I'm trying to apply it in a slightly different way than the article talks about, more specifically using it to conditionally render all of my website except for the `<Nav />` based on the `lastLinkClicked` state. I've got different page classes for each condition as listed in the WEB_PAGES object.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding this method, since I don't have much experience with enums, but my pages aren't rendering correctly. Here's my code:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      x: ...
      y: ...
      z: ...
      lastClickedLink: 'home' //changes to 'new', 'settings', etc. using another function not listed here
    }
  }


  render() {
    function onLinkClick(link) {
      const WEB_PAGES = {
        home: <Home
                x={this.state.x}
              />,
        new: <NewPost />,
        settings: <Settings />,
        signup: <SignUp />,
        login: <Login />
      };
      return (
        <div>
          {WEB_PAGES.link}
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Nav
          y={this.state.y}
          z={this.state.z}
        />
      {onLinkClick(this.state.lastClickedLink)}
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I removed some code for brevity's sake. The error I'm getting with this setup is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined` for home under the WEB_PAGES object.

I initially thought that `this` was pointing to the WEB_PAGES object, but changing `this` to `App` showed that `state` was undefined as well. I'm not really sure what to do at this point.

Is the enums conditional rendering method even doable on this scale? And if not, what other method would be the most ideal for this situation? Many thanks!

Comment: use Immediate invoke Function.

Comment: will you please check the code with replacing the statement from
 {WEB_PAGES.link} to {WEB_PAGES[link]}

Comment: {WEB_PAGES[link]} worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, When you create a function using `function` keyword it creates his own new scope and also creates default object `this`. So while you were trying to access `this.state.x` then it will not state property inside the function. It becomes `this.undefined.x`. so it is giving the error.

Whereas arrow function `{(() => {})}` does not create this object but create internal scope.

try following render method in your code:

```
render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <Nav
        y={this.state.y}
        z={this.state.z}
        />
        {((link) => {
            const WEB_PAGES = {
            home: <Home
                    x={this.state.x}
                />,
            new: <NewPost />,
            settings: <Settings />,
            signup: <SignUp />,
            login: <Login />
            };
            return (
                <div>
                {WEB_PAGES[link]}
                </div>
            );
        })(this.state.lastClickedLink)}
    </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: That got rid of the error, but now all I'm rendering is the Nav, without any of the content in the WEB_PAGE object.

Comment: I think it's supposed to be `<div>{link}</div>`?

Comment: try this one `{WEB_PAGES[link]}`

Comment: @ChristinaW. keep your previous code as it is , but try using the statement {WEB_PAGES[link]} instead of {WEB_PAGES.link}

Comment: @ShubhamBatra can u explain, why she was getting state as undefined?

Answer (score 0):

use `{WEB_PAGES[link]}` when you try to use `.`  it will not work

Answer (score 0):

```
    const Link = ({ lastClickedLink }) => {
      const WEB_PAGES = {
        home: <Home x={lastClickedLink} />,
        new: <NewPost />,
        settings: <Settings />,
        signup: <SignUp />,
        login: <Login />
      };
      return (
        <div>
          {WEB_PAGES[link]}
        </div>
      );
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <Nav
            y={this.state.y}
            z={this.state.z}
          />
          <Link lastClickedLink={lastClickedLink} />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

This variant has more readability and extensibility. Based on Shubham Batra example.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.